# understand read() in Linux

Tags: linux, file, posix, system-calls

I am looking at the man-page for read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count)

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html

where I need some more explanation on the words "On files that support seeking, the read operation commences at the current file offset, and the file offset is incremented by the number of bytes read. "

1) If I want to read a file not from the beginning, say at offset 100 (bytes) to read 1 byte, is the offset 100 added to the fd, i.e, read(fd+100, buf, 1)? If not, how can I specify the offset in the code?

2) How do I know if "files support seeking"? I "opened" the FPGA as a spi device through spi bus, to get the fd. I am using read() to read registers of FPGA. In this case, is the file support seeking?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to first move the file pointer (current file offset) to 100, via a *read* or *seek* call.

Comment: Is the "file pointer" you mentioned the same as file descriptor fd? Do you mean that I first read(fd, buf, 100) and then read(fd, buf, 1)? Thanks!

Comment: No, the file pointer is the internal locator within the opened file. Its initial position upon _open_ is usually 0. Try using the _seek_ call (or fseek if using file pointers rather than file descriptors) after opening the file. That way you don't actually have to spend cycles to move the first 100 bytes over to a buffer, but just move the pointer within the file to the desired place.

Comment: You _could_ read 100 bytes to move the file pointer, and then read 1, but seeking is cleaner and simpler, provided the "file" supports random access in some manner.

Comment: Thanks. It turned out my file does not support seek. The error 29 (Illegal seek) was returned when I used pread. So in this case, do I have to read() 100 bytes to move the offset, and then read() 1 byte? Is this the only way?

Comment: If this pseudo-device really only supports sequential operations, and not random access seeks, it sounds like that's the only way. At least, see if that way works. You're sure that you're not actually seeking off the end (past "EOF")? You're sure you even have the file/pseudo-device properly opened for reading (and permissions allow reading)? Don't forget to check those things.

Comment: Can I move the file pointer to the 101th bytes by reading 100 bytes, and then WRITE the 101th byte, i,e, using read() to move the pointer and then write()?  Because the file (fpga device) may not be writable for all addresses/offsets. So I have to use read() to move the pointer.

Comment: If you open in some sort of read-write mode, you should be able to read 100 bytes and then write the next one. Only experimentation will tell you what works on this particular device, driver, and operating system.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you might be interested in [pread](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pread.2.html), depending on what you are doing.  `pread` is equivalent of atomically (1) saving the current offset, (2) read the offset you want to read, and (3) restoring the original offset.

On your second question you will know if it isn't a seekable device because your call to `lseek` will fail.  I don't know of any reliable way to know in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You use [lseek](http://linux.die.net/man/2/lseek) to move the possition in the file -- so you would do something like

```
lseek(fd, 100, SEEK_SET);
read(fd, buffer, 1);
```

to read one byte at position 100.

However, while this is a valid example, I would advice not to read individual bytes in a file this way, as it is very slow/expensive.

If you want to make random io getting individual bytes in a file at scale, you may be better of usin `mmap` rather than `lseek/read`